# Colum Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was facing issue while loading the huge data using column high chart and i found using boost java script file we can improve the loading time and it works for me but i want graph look like as below **1** but i am getting as  **2** in which  white lines are appearing how can i achieve the same result using boost java script as shown in **1**?

## 1

[Please check the 1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFhPF.png)

## 2

[Please check the 2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpMEy.png)

Here the URL with **#2** output `**http://jsfiddle.net/fa79n3yt/1/**`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you want to display xAxis grid lines. To enable them you need to use `gridLineWidth` property, to colour them use `gridLineColor` and to display them above the series use `gridZIndex`. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineColor
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridZIndex

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1a04tuzv/

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am still able to see the white lines in graph the fiddler link you have given...

Comment: @user3731362 Could you tell me in which browsers this occurs and about OS you use? I tested my example on Chrome, Firefox and IE browsers, Windows 8.1 x64 and I cannot see any lines.

Comment: Please recheck above 1st and 2nd image in my query and you will find the difference.